# Getting the length of a vector in a matrix

Tags: python-3.x

Hi so I have a matrix that's uneven for example

```
[[1,2,3,5,6],    
 [2,3,5,2],   
 [2,4,2]]
```

I'm able to get the sum of each row, but I'm unable to get the length of each row (i.e vector)

Here's my code

```
def mean_vector(v):
  vector_sum = [sum(i) for i in v]
  vector_lengh = [i for i in v] # not quite sure what to do here
  print(vector_lengh)
  vector_mean = vector_sum/vector_lengh
```

in the end, the result should be the average of each row
`[[3.4],[3],[2.6]]`

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Are you looking for [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With your current approach, you would need to do four things:

1. Use [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get the length of the lists in your second list comprehension
2. Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through the two lists in a third list comprehension, and divide out the sum/length pairs
3. Use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to round off the results
4. Return the result from the function

### Working code:

```
def mean_vector(v):
    vector_sum = [sum(i) for i in v]
    vector_lengh = [len(i) for i in v]
    vector_mean = [[round(s / l, 1)] for s, l in zip(vector_sum, vector_lengh)]
    return vector_mean

v = [
    [1,2,3,5,6],
    [2,3,5,2],
    [2,4,2]
]

print(mean_vector(v))
```

### Output:

```
[[3.4], [3.0], [2.7]]
```

### Alternatively, combine all these steps into one:

```
def mean_vector(v):
    return [[round(sum(i) / len(i), 1)] for i in v]

v = [
    [1,2,3,5,6],
    [2,3,5,2],
    [2,4,2]
]

print(mean_vector(v))
```